# Can you send messages through iMessage using iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

Can you send messages through iMessage using iOS Simulator? I would like to get iMessage functionality on my computer in case I don't have my phone with me.

Comment: Voted to close because this isn't programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact, the Simulator isn't built for such things. As a result, you kind of only can run your self-developed apps and use the mobile Safari browser.

Oh, and you can use the built-in "Photos" app. But that's it.

If you really want to send messages over iMessage, get yourself an iPod or iPhone of eBay or so.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.  The iOS simulator does not even have a messaging application.